# Laravel API Post request CSRF token mismatch from localhost

Tags: laravel, csrf

I have my Laravel API hosted on https://api.example.com & a separate Nuxt app hosted on https://frontend.example.com both works fine.

But when I make post requests to my API from localhost nuxt app (localost:3000) I am getting 419 csrf token mismatch error. I am using sanctum for API auth.

But I don't know why I am getting csrf issue here since I have defined all the routes in api.php file. The strange thing is that it is working perfectly in the cloud server but doesn't work from localhost. I have my cors config as below -

```
    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => ['*'],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Comment: CSRF verification requires the session but API requests typically don't use the session so you should probably exclude api routes from CSRF verification. There's [a vague reference in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-tokens-and-spas) about this but if you're not using Sanctum then you might need to roll your own CSRF protection or just not use it. To be clear, the complication is that CSRF protection is meant to prevent cross-site requests, but doing a separate api and frontent app requires you to make cross-site requests so the solution is not trivial

Comment: I have updated the verifyCsrfToken middleware  ```protected $except = [
        '*'
    ];```  Now it is working.